# How to log successful run of ADF pipeline to a table using databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-data-factory

I have a ADF pipelines with multiple stages, I need to log pipeline run id,
pipeline status and all necessary details to a table using databricks.
As I will be connecting the notebook at the end of the pipeline , it will be logging only successful run as per my requirement
wanted to know how to fetch the pipeline name, run id,time taken dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate notebook in Databricks - i.e TableTransactionLog.
Within the notebook you can grab parameters passed by ADF (both hardcoded or dynamic):

You would need to create the Table definition beforehand

In Databricks:

```
# pipelineName from ADF
pipelineName = dbutils.widgets.get("PipelineName")
#print(pipelineName)

# pipelineName from ADF
pipelineParameters = dbutils.widgets.get("PipelineParameters")
#print(pipelineParameters)

# ingestionTimestamp from ADF
lastRunTime = dbutils.widgets.get("LastRunTime")
#print(lastRunTime)

# status from ADF
status = dbutils.widgets.get("Status")
#print(status)

# status from ADF
runStatistics = dbutils.widgets.get("RunStatistics")
#print(runStatistics)

# LayerRan from ADF
layerRan = dbutils.widgets.get("LayerRan")
#print(layerRan)

# creates SQL query that inserts transaction data passed from ADF
if status == 'TRUE':
    query = "INSERT INTO config.tabletransactionlog VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}');".format(pipelineName, pipelineParameters, runStatistics, lastRunTime, status, layerRan)
    #print(query)
    spark.sql(query)
elif status == 'FALSE':
    runStatistics = f'Failed to run {layerRan} notebook - see ADF log'
    query = "INSERT INTO config.tabletransactionlog VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}');".format(pipelineName, pipelineParameters, runStatistics, lastRunTime, status, layerRan)
    #print(query)
    spark.sql(query)
```

In ADF:

Something like this -

[image: ADF]